# Handlebars with Express: different html head for different pages

Tags: express, handlebars.js

I am using Handlebars in an Express Node.js app. My layout.html file includes a `<head>` section. How can I make the `<head>` section different for different pages? (So that I can, for example, reference a JavaScript file in only one page, and vary the `<title>` for each page.)

layout.html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src='/public/ajsfile.js'></script>
    <link type='text/css' href="/public/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    {{{body}}}
  </body>
</html>
```

(I am imagining varying the `<head>` content with something analogous to `{{{body}}}` in the above, but with `{{{head}}}`.)

Comment: https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/using-handlebars-express

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This is a great question and, in my mind, a glaring weakness in Express's view model.  Fortunately, there is a solution: use Handlebars *block helpers*.  Here's the helper I use for this purpose:

```js
helpers: {
    section: function(name, options){
        if(!this._sections) this._sections = {};
        this._sections[name] = options.fn(this);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then, in your layout, you can do the following:

```html
<head>
    {{{_sections.head}}}
</head>
<body>
    {{{body}}}
</body>
```

And in your view:

```html
{{#section 'head'}}
    <!-- stuff that goes in head...example: -->
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
{{/section}}

<h1>Body Blah Blah</h1>
<p>This goes in page body.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks; good solution! (Though perhaps you meant to type {{#section 'head'}} at the start of the view -- missing '#'.)

Comment: is it possible to append if the section already has content? I am implementing partials and some may want to include include content in the head.

Comment: Yes, Don: just modify the helper to append to _sections[name] instead of assigning to

Comment: Here is what I ended up going with, 
if(!this._sections) this._sections = {};
if(!this._sections[name]) this._sections[name] = [];
this._sections[name].push(options.fn(this));

Comment: What is ```this``` referring to here, please ?

Comment: The Handlebars context object

Comment: I tried this but I couldn't seem to get it to work, does the `section` function just get defined via the `hbs.registerHelper` function?

Comment: This solution is designed to work with `express-handlebars`, not `hbs`; I'm sure it could be adapted to work with `hbs`, but it should work out of the box with `express-handlebars`.

Comment: @DonP I tried your code but no matter what I do my head section ends up in the `<body>` section. Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: Hi, @DonP, nope that's all there is too it.  Without seeing your code, I can't know what's not working for you.  I created a minimal demo, maybe that will help you: https://github.com/EthanRBrown/express-handlebars-section-demo

Comment: thanks a lot, been looking for this! works with nodemailer-express-handlebars package

Answer (score 10):

You can make the follow:

#### layout.hbs

```
<head>
    <title>{{title}}</title>
    {{#each css}}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/{{this}}" />
    {{/each}}
</head>
```

#### app.js

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'MyApp', css: ['style.css', 'custom.css'] });
});
```

## Result:

```
<head>
    <title>MyApp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/custom.css" />
</head>
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, you could use this implementation of the section helper: https://github.com/cyberxander90/express-handlebars-sections

You just need to install it and enable it:

`yarn add express-handlebars-sections # or npm`

```
const expressHandlebarsSections = require('express-handlebars-sections');

app.engine('handlebars', expressHandlebars({
    section: expressHandlebarsSections()
}));
```

Hope it helps.

Younes

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question but I wanted to point out a clear alternative solution to what you are asking (I'm not entirely sure why nobody else spoke about it over the years). You actually had the answer you were looking for when you bring up placing things in {{{head}}} like you do for {{{body}}}, but I guess you needed help understanding how to make it work.

It seems possible that most of the answers on this page are geared towards Node "Sections" because you speak about the different sections of HTML you've included in your layout file that you want to change. The "Sections"  everyone is speaking about in this thread seems to be a technique, although I may be mistaken, originating from Microsoft's Razor Template Engine. More info: https://mobile.codeguru.com/columns/dotnet/using-sections-and-partials-to-manage-razor-views.htm

Anyway Sections work for your question, and so could "Partials" theoretically (although it may not actually be the best option for this). More info on Partials:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-partial

However, you simply asked for a way to alter the HTML tag content of your template layout in Handlebars, and assuming we are talking about HTML head tags, all you need to do is replace the content you have in your template layout HTML head tags with one of these (I use 3 brackets because it seems HTML would be included and you don't want it escaped):

```
<head> 
{{{headContent}}}
</head>
```

Then you just dynamically pass whatever data you want through the route you create in your app.js file to "get" the page like so (I am mostly taking the code @Fabricio already provided so I didn't have to rewrite this):

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.render( 'index', { headContent:'I DID IT!' });
});
```

Now when you load your page, "I DID IT!" will be where you expect it to show up.

Comment: Because we want to pass head content from Our hbs page to the layout and not from nodejs route.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem, if I need to modify all my `res.render` would be a hard work. The best solution is use sections buy this solution is still poor. I am looking for something like overriding Handlebars render to search for a header in the view and append it to the layout.