# How are handlebar block helper functions defined for the command line tool?

Tags: handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I am using the handlebars templating language in the command line mode for creating Latex files. The handlebars documentation describes how handlebars can be extended (http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html. Since I am using handlebars on the command line tool handlebarsjs-cli, where does the definition of the new block helper go? Let's for example assume that I want to define the bold helper from the example file:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('bold', function(options) {
  return new Handlebars.SafeString(
      '<div class="mybold">'
      + options.fn(this)
     + '</div>');
});
```

Where do I put that code?

Comment: I don't think this is possible with handlebarsjs-cli, if you need such things I'll advise you to switch to a node.js script.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a variable in your server.js:

```
// the var css is to give a specific css style sheet to the login page

var css = {helpers: {
    section: function(name, options){
        if(!this._sections) this._sections = {};
        this._sections[name] = options.fn(this);
        return null;
    }
}}

// pass the var css in

app.get("/", function(req,res){
    res.render("logIn", css)
});
```

([Inspiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737057/handlebars-with-express-different-html-head-for-different-pages))

Comment: This is not relevant to the use of the handlebars-cli, as the question pertains to.